# Cannot Fully Clear the Items from a Winforms ComboBox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox

The title is somewhat misleading. I can reduce the .Items Count to zero by the usual methods, but the dropdown list area keeps its former dimensions.

1. When adding items to ComboBox manually, I can do ComboBox.Items.Clear. The ComboBox.Items count is reduced to zero.
2. When databinding ComboBox, I can do ComboBox.DataSource = Nothing. Or, set the BindingSource = Nothing, if using one. The ComboBox.Items Count is reduced to zero.

However, the combobox dropdown area retains the rows it had been populated with, except that they are "empty". In other words, it's a white box which is the same height as the list it had contained.

Seems to me that if I clear a ComboBox, it ought to appear identical to one which has never been bound or filled.

The DropDownStyle = DropDownList

**ComboBox before filling/binding:**

[image: ComboBox before filling/binding]

**ComboBox after filling/binding:**

[image: ComboBox after filling/binding]

**ComboBox after clearing/setting datasource/bindingsource = Nothing:**

[image: ComboBox after clearing/setting datasource/bindingsource = Nothing]

Does anyone know a way to prevent this? If I unbind or otherwise clear the ComboBox, I'd like the dropdown to then consist of one empty row, as in the first image.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set the DropDownHeight property of the ComboBox control after clearing the DataSource.  Here is an example that sets it back to a default that you can adapt for your own purposes.

```
Private m_intDefaultDropDownHeight As Integer = 1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim lstItems As New List(Of String)

    lstItems.Add("A")
    lstItems.Add("B")
    lstItems.Add("C")

    m_intDefaultDropDownHeight = ComboBox1.DropDownHeight

    ComboBox1.DataSource = lstItems

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ComboBox1.DataSource = Nothing
    ComboBox1.DropDownHeight = m_intDefaultDropDownHeight
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works well. What a shame, though, that after all these years Microsoft hasn't fixed it. And what a shame that in all the years I've been working with this control I'd not noticed this bug. I suppose I hadn't ever needed to "reset" all of a Form's controls until now...

Comment: I'm going with this one as answer as being the one which speaks most directly to the cause of the bug. The other methods presented are perfectly fine, as well. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 2):

The following should fix that:

```
ComboBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown
ComboBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
```

For some reason changing the 'DropDownStyle' property of the combobox to something that is not `DropDownList`, and then changing it back resizes the DropDownList to the minimum possible height for its entries, or at least in Visual Studio 2015 with .NET Framework 4.5. Hope this helps.

Edit: It's strange that if the ComboBox's style is `ComboBoxStyle.DropDown` that `ComboBox.DropDownHeight = 106` will change the height, but if the style is `ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList` it won't. Yet another mystery of .NET!

Comment: I believe the second line is unnecessary, but you're on the right track. Just executing lines 1 and 3 seems to do the trick. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: You're correct and I have edited my post accordingly :)

Answer (score 2):

To force reset a height of dropdown element you need to change `ComboBox.DropDownStyle` to some other and back to the original

```
Me.ComboBox1.DataSource = Nothing
Me.ComboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown
Me.ComboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
```

Comment: This works as well, likely because it resets the DropDownHeight. Rather than saving the original DropDownHeight as described above and reusing the value, however, I simply set mine to 106, which was the original height.

Comment: @whistlebritches, 106 is hardcoded value of `DefaultDropDownHeight` property in the `ComboBox` control.

Comment: yes - I checked the DropDownHeight value before populating the ComboBox and for now am using the value that I found (106). However, looking into reflected ComboBox code, I see that the default height can vary depending upon styles, the OS and other factors. I will end up either saving the starting DropDownHeight and reapplying it, or simply changing the DropDownStyle temporarily.